# Запятые в примере со словами "в принципе" и "правда"

Tags: пунктуация

Отдохнули, в принципе, неплохо, правда, под конец погода слегка испортила настроение. Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Answer (score 3):

Запятые расставлены верно. Подробно о пунктуации этих слов см. здесь. [Справочник по пунктуации.](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=767.hsSVsISlo93st4kRbCB5-wGXzVnZQvuu_CXq7QjoScaHU9UhZdI15QjoO5vdZvUVj0vC_Q0YFzu0C9FJvT_8rA.25545952dabae03e63024173fad030cf1341b6ce&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0-qwflIRTTifi6VAA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDTTdORUZYeDB1Y3paMmRiWVdaNTVQXzlMdU1kR1BjRExPOVctWDlXMDU1N1ZwSmcybWllQzh3NW5vdUl5MjE2SVlaLS1DUDVyWW1Xb01xZEIySWJ4bw&b64e=2&sign=a001c15b733301ebc505219706aad7c2&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk9yxWwwVth7UJAXWFElFlfg87jHpNySW0scPu99rxMIPGQERCIq2nnR0YkIOiHFB664q7sEVoOYWKx0H6rLpaRCSpDCnZZLS2TWMgo-VqKcgsZ5FPGrDHmqNEfSgrytRUVa2kLjvVK87EjKYqY-XQhq7T5F0yvi5Gs6dT0Llpy6wpRGeh_P82Qwyc-s-wcN9CQ&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCCIlkcOrsGUOP7ebdLg6P9hougzPn7e83VSiDvxW83j91v43UUC1WpfaO1HzbKJne8C9kNX8bi3d9nuj9qhrKST7pPNYeSVGE5i-Go1NKyV0DXp01oZtvE2W1goBIc3tRnDGQ-2tIXwESmR-59_BCyHHJjhrvg9j38pN1QH5bOGU&l10n=ru&cts=1438411052647&mc=1.584962500721156)

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта:

а) Отдохнули, в принципе (=в сущности говоря), неплохо, правда, под конец погода слегка испортила настроение.

б) Отдохнули в принципе (=в целом) неплохо, правда, под конец погода слегка испортила настроение.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Семантика значений следующая. Вводное слово: в сущности говоря, по сути говоря. Наречие: в целом, в основном. Но эта семантика различается с трудом, обособление часто бывает авторским.

2) А вот структура важна. Вводное слово - это всегда второй план речи, тест как бы прерывается, а потом возвращается на основную линию, и структура должна обеспечить такой переход. В нашем случае возможны оба структурных варианта.

3) Есть еще интересная особенность:  иногда на вводное слово падает логическое ударение, и тогда оно уже точно вводным словом не является и не обособляется.

Примеры

Я, в принципе, достаточно лояльный человек в этих вопросах. В принципе, вариантов предлагается множество.

Такое общество в прИнципе не может быть "правовым". Пять хороших самолётов "на коленке" мы в принципе соберём.

Символ в прИнципе защищён от опытного опровержения: он поверяется иным опытом. Символ, в принципе, защищЁн от опытного опровержения: он поверяется иным опытом.  Здесь разная семантика зависит от логического ударения.

Answer (score 1):

*"В принципе"* чаще не обособляется. Возможная пунктуация:

***Отдохнули в принципе неплохо, правда, под конец погода слегка испортила настроение.***

Возможно, в принципе, и обособление этого *"в принципе"*. Но, на мой взгляд, такое решение лишь затруднит прочтение разбираемого предложения:

***Отдохнули, в принципе, неплохо, правда,*** *под конец погода…*

Четыре запятые на четыре первых слова?..

Может, лучше разбить это предложение (с обособленным *"в принципе"*) на два простых предложения, поставив после *"неплохо"* точку?